# How to view selected item in listbox in image viewer asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, getfiles, image-viewer

I have this code that populates my listbox that contains what I type in the textbox. My problem is how can I view the selected item in my `listbox`  in a `image viewer` since all my files are images? Am I missing something?

Here's my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Clear();
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images"), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);


        foreach (string item in files)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(item);
            if (fileName.ToLower().Contains(TextBox1.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(fileName);
            }

        }
    }

protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DocumentImage.ImageUrl = Directory.GetDirectories("~/images") + ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Directory.GetDirectories("~/images") is returning an array, so you are essentially trying to combine an array with a string (String[] + string).

Comment: @JuStDaN What should I do then?

Answer (score 2):

This should work I think:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox1.Items.Clear();
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images"), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (string item in files)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(item);
        if (fileName.ToLower().Contains(TextBox1.Text.ToLower()))
        {
            string subPath = item.Substring(Server.MapPath("~/images").Length).Replace("\\","/");
            ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(fileName, subPath));
        }
    }
}
```

In this part, you need to not only have the file name, but also the path where the file was found. In my sample, the sub path where the file was found is first set into `subPath` and that is then stored as the value for the list item.

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DocumentImage.ImageUrl = "~/images" + ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value;
}
```

Here we use the sub path to set the correct url to the image.

Note that you need to have the `AutoPostBack` set to true on the `DocumentImage` in your `asxp` page in order for the image to change when you change the selection in the list box.